# JavaScript цикл event

Tags: javascript, html, функции, циклы

Как через цикл сделать активацию того или иного input? Можно конечно прописать каждой по функции, но очевидно что это не самый правильный способ...

```js
function selectFunc() {
  document.getElementById('text1').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('text2').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('text3').disabled = true;
  document.getElementById('text4').disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="radio" name="sel" onclick="selectFunc();"> <input type="text" id="text1"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="sel" onclick="selectFunc();"> <input type="text" id="text2"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="sel" onclick="selectFunc();"> <input type="text" id="text3"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="sel" onclick="selectFunc();"> <input type="text" id="text4">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.name === "sel") {
    for (var id of ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"]) {
      document.getElementById(id).disabled = id !== e.target.value
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="radio" name="sel" value="text1"> <input type="text" id="text1"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="sel" value="text2"> <input type="text" id="text2"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="sel" value="text3"> <input type="text" id="text3"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="sel" value="text4"> <input type="text" id="text4">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Передавай в функцию параметр.

```
<input type="radio" name="sel" onclick="selectFunc(1);"> <input type="text" id="text1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="sel" onclick="selectFunc(2);"> <input type="text" id="text2"><br>
```

А в ней уже цикл, или что там нужно.

```
function selectFunc(nom) {
    if (nom==1)
```